# What's wrong with my debug screen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was recently playing in my Minecraft Realm with my friends and I needed the coordinates of my position for a command-block creation we were making. I brought up the debug screen, but it had no coordinates.
[image]

As you can see, my coordinates are not shown, only my chunk-relative position.

I *was* eventually able to get my coordinates by using `/execute rappatic` (rappatic is my username) and hitting TAB thrice, which showed my current position, but there must be an easier way to do it.
Why are my coordinates not shown on my debug screen?

Comment: BTW, the `/execute` thing shows the coordinates of the block you're looking at, not your own coordinates. To get those printed to chat, you could for example use `/data get entity @s Pos`. When this question was asked, the best way to get your exact coordinates without F3 would have probably been `/entitydata @s {}` and then searching for "`Pos`" in the game log. Or maybe summoning a temporary dummy armour stand without gravity, getting its data (which is shorter) and then killing it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server has the `gamerule reducedDebugInfo true` set.

This is a setting to give less gameplay-related information in the debug screen. It hides your coordinates, your block coordinates, your facing direction, the biome you're in, the light levels, the local difficulty and the coordinates of the block you're looking at, as well as the lines of F3+B (hitboxes) and F3+G (chunk grid).

The reason it's set on some servers is to prevent players from using the debug screen in their regular Survival play, because it's originally intended only for debug purposes and some people consider it cheating to use it in Survival.

There usually is no reason to set it on a Creative server with access to commands. If the server owner allows it, you can change it with `/gamerule reducedDebugInfo false`.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2k82mx/f3_key_does_not_show_xyz_coordinates/), you can solve this through Options>Multiplayer Settings>Reduced Debug Info: Off.

Comment: This of course only applies if you originally turned it on yourself, which the asker didn't, but someone else reading this post might.